# Set image source to another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two images, and i want to set the src of the first image to the second one, knowing that the source will keep on changing i can't keep it the same, how can i do that? here is what i have tried so far:

```js
$("#image2").attr("src","/images");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image1" width="50" height="50" src="/images">
 <img id="image2" width="50" height="50" src="">
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to link the two images automatically. You just need to make the function that changes the image change them both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use onload on the first image. I did this inline since we need to catch the onload on the tag and not after load.
This will change the second image whenever the first image changes

```html
<img id="image1" width="50" height="50" 
src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-50-50-1.jpg" 
onload="document.getElementById('image2').src=this.src">

<img id="image2" width="50" height="50" src="">
```

Comment: I upvoted this because you used plain JS instead of jQuery

Comment: good answer - though you have inline js which is bad practice and shouldn't be encouraged. It leads to hard-to-maintain code, should be in an external js file but otherwise +1! :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I agree, however in this example you would need to have a dummy image and script an extra change since you cannot assign a load handler after the tag without having to trigger it too

Comment: @mplungjan it'd still rather set that all up than inline js haha but I understand why now :)

Comment: @mplungjan I'm getting the images from my database in a for loop, does this work on it?

Comment: that depends. You have not given enough information as to how you write the HTML and also not why you want to copy. Please update the question with the code that creates the image tags - and include the loop

Comment: @mplungjan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103801/displaying-images-in-specific-divs-from-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to read the src-attribute from the first image and set it to the second image? Then you can simply do:

```
$("#image2").attr("src", $("#image1").attr("src"));
```

Comment: mm you are missing the info _the source will keep changine_

Comment: this works but isn't dynamic enough for changing elements - I can't imagine the id to always be image2 or image1

Comment: @SagarV I think she means on the server side, when the page is generated. Well if I understood incorrectly this won't help.