# Displaying images in specific divs from for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple images that are being saved in my database, and I'm getting them in my HTML page using a for loop, what I want after getting those images is to display them in different divs, they should be displayed in the "cropit-preview-image", here is my code:

```html
@foreach($Images AS $image)
<img id="{{$image['ImageID']}}" src="/uploads/{{$image['ImageLink']}}">
            @endforeach


<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
<div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
<div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<img class="cropit-preview-image" alt="" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
<div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
<div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<img class="cropit-preview-image" alt="" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
<div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
<div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<img class="cropit-preview-image" alt="" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
<div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
<div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<img class="cropit-preview-image" alt="" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want the actual resulting HTML to be?  What happens when you put the HTML you want into your loop?

Comment: @David The for loop brings the images from the db and displays them randomly in my page, i want them to be displayed inside a specific place

Comment: Just get your "cropit-preview-image" html and put it inside loop, it's just that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($Images AS $image)

    //this code here will be repeated x times where x is equal with number of images that $Images array has
    //so if you have two images then all this html inside loop will be printed out 2 times.

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
        <div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
            <div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <img class="cropit-preview-image" id="{{$image['ImageID']}}" src="/uploads/{{$image['ImageLink']}}" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Here you have a good reference [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) where you can learn more about how loops work in php.

Also it looks like you are using laravel. If so i would suggest you to use `@forelse` so you can easily handle it when you don't have any image.

```
@forelse ($Images AS $image)

    //this code here will be repeated x times where x is equal with number of images that $Images array has
    //so if you have two images then all this html inside loop will be printed out 2 times.

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
        <div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
            <div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <img class="cropit-preview-image" id="{{$image['ImageID']}}" src="/uploads/{{$image['ImageLink']}}" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@empty

    <p>No images</p>

@endforelse
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the complete div structure inside your for loop, with the image tag, as follow

```
@foreach($Images AS $image)

<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 image-editor text-center">
<div class="cropit-preview" style="position: relative; width: 263px; height: 251px;">
<div class="cropit-preview-image-container" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; right: 0px; left: auto; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<img class="cropit-preview-image" id="{{$image['ImageID']}}" src="/uploads/{{$image['ImageLink']}}" style="transform-origin: right top 0px; will-change: transform;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```